# Why is my ValidationMessageFor For TextArea Displaying on Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, validation

When my page loads my ValidationSummary and ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestNumbersString) both display the validation error despite just barely loading the page. I have checked that the .css file is referenced in my _Layout.cshtml and the styles exist for it.

Model.cs

```
[Required]
public string TestNumbersString { get; set; }
```

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

partialView.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form" }))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TestNumbersString, new { @class = "testBox" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestNumbersString)
}
```

My Layout I noticed has a number of javascript and css files, but other validation works on the page, AND I know that the site.css is loaded for other parts of the page (but not for my form, but that's another problem).

_Layout.cshtml

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The troubleshooting I've done so far has lead me to find that the class for the validation message is field-validation-error. So I am lead to believe it's not a .css error (even though the css styling isn't applying correctly).

I also want to be clear that this is a partial layout. I'm not sure if this would cause additional problems when dealing with validation.

### **EDIT: Solution**

Thanks to @jacqijvv for the solution.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TestModel model = new TestModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
//We have these separate as this is the design for MVC.
public ActionResult Index(TDMixParametersViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);
    else
    {
        model = new TDMixParametersViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the parameter from the action method call

E.g.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TestModel model = new TestModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

That should fix the problem

Comment: This fixed it. If you have the time, could you give me an explanation as to why this works this way?

Comment: Quickhorn, this is because of the way how MVC's builtin routing works. The HTTPGET function, the Index action you called, does not expect a model as parameter, that is why validation fails immediately. The default is either no parameters or id, for HTTPGET methods and for HTTPPOST methods it is FormCollection or model, because it posts back those values when the form is submitted. Or something like that :-)

Comment: @jacqijw Thank you kindly! I've separated my response into two actions. All the tutorials have you do this, but I was messing around and never switched back to the two actions. I never would have thought it would mess up validation.

Answer (score 0):

You have your css file included at the top of the page right? It is recommended to put css files on the top in the head and javascript files at the end of the body

Try putting the site.css file before the JavaScript files in your _layout.cshtml

Comment: I just tried moving the JS files to the end of the body and it did not fix the problem, unfortunately.